# Problem updating to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, release-upgrade

I accidentally exited do-release-upgrade using cmd+c. It was in the middle of doing a MySQL upgrade and it was asking me about what it wanted to do with the my.cnf file any suggestions?
Really need help with this ASAP

this is what I know is going on at the moment

```
 jonny_flowers@pickles10:~$ ps aux | grep update 

 root     13890  0.0 0.8 147312 71656 ?        S    22:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /tmp/update-manager-nFjl_2/precise --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText 

 1000     25813  0.0  0.0   9372   884 pts/4    S+   23:32   0:00 grep --color=auto update
```

Answer (score 1):

restarted the machine and typed sudo-apt upgrade and went from there